# Из очереди проверок "У меня та же проблема"

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок в разделе "Сообщения низкого качества" есть такой пункт при рекомендации удаления "У меня та же проблема".

Её описание:

> Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие
>   вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «Задать вопрос».
>   Дополнительно вы можете добавить вознаграждение, чтобы привлечь к
>   вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша репутация достигнет достаточного
>   уровня.

На мой взгляд, выглядит немного некорректно. Что значит фактически? Это напрямую не является ответом на вопрос. Может исправить и сделать, например, так:

> Не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие
>   вопросы, вы можете задать их, нажав на кнопку «Задать вопрос».
>   Дополнительно вы можете добавить вознаграждение, чтобы привлечь к
>   вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша репутация достигнет достаточного
>   уровня.

Comment: Вы фактически предлагаете убрать "фактически".

Comment: Это временный эксперимент - сменили заголовки причин и смотрят как увеличится профит от этого. Если всё получится - сменят и остальное.

Comment: @Other мне казалось, сменили только в причинах закрытия.

Comment: @alexolut еще запятая перед словом "нажав" и после него же "на" добавил.